# Using tab key to trigger event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using space key to translate entered text using Google API. I want same task to be achieved using tab key.

```
<script>
function OnLoad() {
  var options = {
    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
    transliterationEnabled: true
  };

  var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
  control.makeTransliteratable(["txtHindi"]);
  var keyVal = 32; // Space key
  //var keyTab = 9;  //tab key
  $("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 9) {
      var engText = $("#txtEnglish").val() + " ";
      var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
      $("#txtHindi").val($("#txtHindi").val() + engTextArray[engTextArray.length - 2]);
      document.getElementById("txtHindi").focus();
      $("#txtHindi").trigger({
        type: 'keypress',
        keyCode: keyVal,
        which: keyVal,
        charCode: keyVal
      });
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
      $("#txtHindi").val("");
      $("#txtEnglish").val("");
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#txtHindi").bind("keyup", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#txtEnglish").val($("#txtEnglish").val() + " ");
      document.getElementById("txtEnglish").focus()
    }, 0);
  });
} //end onLoad function

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? `event.keyCode === 9` should match the tab key.

Comment: `keyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated. I would suggest you tu use `event.key === 'Tab'` see https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-whitespace which does not depend of your keyboard (qwerty / azerty ...)

Comment: problem is when i press tab key,the text in english box gets copied correctly to the hindi box and trigger part is working fine too.just the translation part is not getting executed...(  " document.getElementById("txtHindi").focus();  ") .the focus() function mentioned in the above statement does this translation part but it is not working :(